# Date field filter is not working in Row Group level filter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have added a Filter in Row Group-> Group Properties to perform sum of quantity only for those transactions which have done before a certain date.

Whenever I am selecting the 'Cdate' as Expression field from my dataset1, the type is showing as Date/Time but after saving it when I check,I found it as 'Text'. As a result the filter for 'cDate' is not working during report generation.

Note that, I can't filter the data in dataset side or tablix side as I have to show all the column items. This is a matrix report.

Comment: Does "CDate" refer to the name of a field in your dataset or to the function CDate()? Can you include a screenshot of how you have set up the filter?

Comment: Yes "CDate" is a field of my dataset...I can't upload image as I dont have enough reputation. I just select Row Group-> Group Properties-> Filter then add filter...select the Cdate in expression filed and then select operator(<=), then select the value as Parameter value which is a Date/Time parameter...

Answer (score 1):

OK this is going to be a bit confusing because your dataset contains a field with the same name as one of the built-in expression functions ("CDate" - Convert to Date).

I sometimes run into these datatype issues when using filters and I find the best way to handle it is to force both the filter field and the filter value to be the same data type.

So in your case try setting the Filter expression to:

```
=CDate(Fields!CDate.Value)
```

then select the operator as "<=" and set the value using an expression as well:

```
=CDate(Parameters!MyParameter.value)
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Nathan,
 Thanks for reply.. I will try this one although I have changed the Dataset and fulfill my requirement in other way..But I will obviously try this one as I want to find out the a way for future. I had tried by using CDate function only for DataSet field and it was not work on that time...Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

I understand you so that your date field in the dataset is called CDate, try casting it as date, so instead of selecting it in your filter, type the following into the filter
`=CDate(Fields!CDate.Value)`